# standalone webrtc application linux

Tags: video-streaming, raspberry-pi, webrtc, beagleboneblack

I want to build a `standalone video chat application` using `Raspberry pi/ Beaglebone` board (linux based).

I have compiled the
`WebRTC API` (libjingle_peerconnection library) but during runtime, it says

```
libjingle_peerconnection_so.so : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Kindly provide the solution for this or any other alternative to achieve the objective.